# Bash script - how can I match only 1 byte from a 4 byte hexadecimal value

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sed

I am trying to filter only one byte (nibbles 2 and 3 after `xx` - little endian) from 4 bytes (32 bit) hexadecimal output i get. 
When i execute a command, I get the following output

```
000023xx
```

`xx` varies and is not fixed.

I am trying to write a bash script to see if the output I get matches with `23`. When I use the following, it matches to `23xx` where `xx` is between 2-3 but i wanted something that match only `23` after `xx` (little endian)

**Examples**

```
val=231a
echo $val | grep -o -E '[2-3]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
23

val=2332
echo $val | grep -o -E '[2-3]+' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'
2332
```

In the second example, I wanted an output of `23`.

Comment: looks like this works - echo $val | grep -o -E '[2-3].' | head -1 | sed -e 's/^0\+//'

Comment: You can also simply do it with bash *character indexes*, e.g. `[[ ${val:4:4} = 23?? ]]` That will validate that characters `4-7` (zero based index) in `val` match `23??`.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `bash` alone; no need for other tools.

```
val=231a
if [[ $val = *23?? ]]; then
    echo "$val matches"
else
    echo "$val doesn't match"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do AND (&) and right-shift (>>) in Arithmetic expansions:

```
(( ((val >> 8) & 0xFF) == 0x23 )) && echo "value is 23"
```

Just be careful with parentheses! and prefix the hexadecimal value with `0x`

```
val=0x231a
```

the code means:

- remove the last 8 bits (`>> 8`),
- remove any other bit above the last 8 (`& 0xFF`), and
- compare the result with hex 23 (`== 0x23`).

If the result is `true` execute: `echo "value is 23"`.

---

If the value is actually "little endian", then the hexadecimal value from a string `0000231a` is:

```
val=0x1a230000
```

And the code will be:

```
(( ((val >> 16) & 0xFF) == 0x23 )) && echo "value is 23"
```

---

or doing it in text, if the string in val is `val=0000231a`, just do:

```
[[ val == *23?? ]] && echo "value is 23"
```

---

and, if you want to extract nibbles 2 and 3 from the string, do:

```
$ result=${val: -4:2}
$ echo "$result"
23
```

Or shorter:

```
$ echo "${val: -4:2}"
23
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in just one line by using Bash regular expressions:

```
[[ $val =~ 23..$ ]] && echo match
```